# Capture video from WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, video-capture

I want to write a C# application which can record a video capture of one of its WPF controls.

Is there a solution in .Net to record video from a control, or is there some library I could use?

My goal is to write a SketchCast application. The use case is the following:

1. launch SketchCast app and press record button,
2. write ink into a WPF ink area, and talk,
3. press stop,
4. recorded voice and ink animation get
   saved into a video file in some
   encoding.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to write this application yourself, you can use [Windows Media Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/encoder/default.mspx)(*) and restrict the screen capture to a single window. Just set your WPF control to fill the entire window and remove the window border. WME has support for voice recording during screen captures.

(*) or any other screencast software with these features